# How to determine Young's modulus of a wire by Searle's method?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, units, measurement-problem

The question is:

> A student performs an experiment to determine the Young's modulus of a wire, exactly 2m long, by [Searle's method](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=searle+method+young+modulus). In a particular reading, the student measures the extension in the length of the wire to be 0.8mm with an uncertainty of 0.05mm at a load of exactly 1.0Kg. The student also measure the diameter of the wire to be 0.4mm with an uncertainty of + or - 0.01m. Take g=9.8m/s^2(exact). Calculate the Young's modulus.

Explain me what is Young's modulus and how it is related to Searle's method. Is there any equation to solve this problem?

Comment: Why ask when you have googled?

Comment: i din google it

Comment: Then you don't know how to use internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Young's modulus is given by the ratio of tensile stress over extensional strain; the formula:

$$Y=\frac{(F/A)}{(\Delta L /L_0)}=\frac{FL_0}{A\Delta L}$$

where $F$ is the force applied, $A$ is the cross-sectional area, $L_0$ the original length and $\Delta L$ the extension or change in length of the object. In your case, $L_0=2 \, \mathrm{m}$. As stated in the question, the diameter of the wire is $d=0.0008 \, \mathrm{m}$. Therefore the radius $r=d/2$, and the area is given by,

$$A=\pi r^2 = \frac{\pi}{4} d^2=5.027 \times 10^{-7} \, \mathrm{m}^2$$

as we have assumed a cross-section of the wire is a perfect circle. The force applied is given by Newton's second law, $F=ma$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Young's modulus of wire material is given by,
\begin{align}
Y=\frac{\text{stress}}{\text{strain}}=\frac{F/A}{l/L}=\frac{4FL}{\pi d^2 l}.
\end{align}
From given data, $F=mg=9.8\;\mathrm{N}$, $L=2.0\;\mathrm{m}$, $l=0.8\times{10}^{-3}\;\mathrm{m}$, and $d=0.4\times{10}^{-3}\;\mathrm{m}$. Substitute the values in equation to  get $Y=1.95\times{10}^{11}\approx 2.0\times{10}^{11}\;\mathrm{N/m^2}$. 

Differentiate the expression for $Y$ and simplify to get error in $Y$,
\begin{align}
\label{zha:eqn:2}
{\Delta Y}/{Y}=2\,{\Delta d}/{d}+{\Delta l}/{l}.
\end{align}
 Substitute $\Delta d=0.01\;\mathrm{mm}$ and $\Delta l=0.05\;\mathrm{mm}$ to get,
\begin{align}
\Delta Y=Y (2\times0.01/0.4+0.05/0.8)=Y(0.1125)\approx 0.2\times{10}^{11}\;\mathrm{N/m^2}.
\end{align}